# How do you authenticate to VSTS using LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, libgit2sharp

I'm trying to clone a VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services) repository using LibGit2Sharp. I'm setting up a `CredentialsHandler` and `UsernamePasswordCredentials` representing my Microsoft Account's credentials, and the result I get is this:

```
LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Too many redirects or authentication replays
  Source=LibGit2Sharp
```

If I can't even pass in my actual username and password, I'm not sure what might work.

I also tried using `DefaultCredentials` as mentioned [here](http://quabr.com/33612253/libgit2sharp-and-tfs-git-repository), but that appears to be only for TFS, not VSTS (NTLM credentials for TFS).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to enable alternate authentication for your account. Follow the steps below to do this:

1. Login VSTS Web Portal.
2. Click your account name and select "My profile" from up right corner.
3. Switch to "Security" panel.
4. Select "Alternate authentication credentials" and configure it.

[image]

Then you can use the alternative credential to authenticate to VSTS. Following code shows how to authenticate to VSTS and perform a clone job.

```
using LibGit2Sharp;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string surl = "https://youraccount.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/Remoterepo";
            string lpath = "C:\\LocalPath";
            CloneOptions co = new CloneOptions();
            string un = "alternativeusername";
            string pwd = "alternativepassword";
            Credentials ca = new UsernamePasswordCredentials() {Username = un, Password = pwd };
            co.CredentialsProvider = (_url, _user, _cred) => ca ;
            Repository.Clone(surl,lpath,co);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. I had actually gone into that area and done everything right except I had thought I could still use my primary email address and password, with just the checkbox now checked. It appears you really must enter a secondary username to make this work.
Do you have any idea whether the Git Credential Manager for Windows (https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) would allow using the regular credentials?