# Authorization with TFS PAT in libgit2sharp

Tags: git, tfs, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I'd like to access in-premise TFS server GIT repositories using LibGit2Sharp. So far I'm only playing around with this library, and I can't get it to work as I'd expect it would.

My first problem is authorization with Personal Access Tokens. I can clone a repository using UsernamePasswordCredentials providing my company email and password, however, I can't find a way to do so with PAT. I can't find any reliable information about it, so I tried using it in different combinations, like replacing my password/username with it, but I can't get it to work - I always get LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: 'too many redirects or authentication replays'.

It's supposed to mean credentials are invalid, but I'm sure my token is valid and I authorized all scopes, so it should be able to do everything I am able to with my credentials. Is there an example I could follow to get it up and running? Here's my current solution with username and password that works:

```
        var co = new CloneOptions();
        co.CredentialsProvider = (_url, _user, _cred) =>
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials
            {
                Username = "username@companyname.com",
                Password = "password"
            };

        Repository.Clone(@"remoteUrl-received-from-api", "destination-folder", co);
```

My other question is, which URL received from this API endpoint: [TFS API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/repositories) is the correct one to pass to LibGit2Sharp? I'm using the "remoteUrl"(which is the TFS web app URL) to clone and it works when provided with username and password, however, Repository.IsValid returns false. I'm not that familiar with TFS and GIT so please forgive my complete lack of knowledge in this area.

If I don't get this working tomorrow I'll have to use a cmd.exe process and console commands, which I would really like to avoid - so any help would be really apprecieated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In libgit2sharp, seems passing the token as the username with a blank password is specific to **GitHub**. This may not works well with TFS/VSTS hosted git repo.

Take a look at this related question in GITHUB: [Does Git-Clone support Personal access tokens ?](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1256)

For TFS/VSTS, if you don't want to  use UsernamePasswordCredentials providing your company email and password, you could use **Alternate authentication credentials** instead.

[image]

For the url, you should use the TFS git remoterepo url. More detail sample please refer this link: [How do you authenticate to VSTS using LibGit2Sharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927437/how-do-you-authenticate-to-vsts-using-libgit2sharp)

You can use the alternative credential to authenticate to VSTS. Following code shows how to authenticate to VSTS and perform a clone job.

```
using LibGit2Sharp;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string surl = "https://youraccount.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/Remoterepo";
            string lpath = "C:\\LocalPath";
            CloneOptions co = new CloneOptions();
            string un = "alternativeusername";
            string pwd = "alternativepassword";
            Credentials ca = new UsernamePasswordCredentials() {Username = un, Password = pwd };
            co.CredentialsProvider = (_url, _user, _cred) => ca ;
            Repository.Clone(surl,lpath,co);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was afraid that was the case. It also seems PAT doesn't work with git console commands aswell, so there's no real alternative to credentials/alternative credentials.

Comment: Actually you can normally use Git command with PAT like this:   

    git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $($env:System_AccessToken)" fetch

Answer (score 4):

Using any username and a **personal access token** as password works with **git on Azure DevOps (VSTS)**. This way you can restrict access to the bare minimum.

Assuming that your CloneOptions, FetchOptions, ... variable has the name "o":

```
o.CredentialsProvider = (url, fromUrl, types) => new UsernamePasswordCredentials(){Username="Anything", Password = "Your personal access token here" };
```

I don't know if it will work with TFS.

Comment: I was looking specifically for VSTS / Azure Devops and this question came up. Thanks very much! Where did you get the info?

Comment: Glad I could help! I don't recall where I found this info.